# Using @Html.EditorFor to create new model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to render a form used to create a new instance of a Model. I tried,

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => new Person())
```

But I got the error,

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

I tried,

```
@Html.EditorForModel("MyNamespace.Person")
```

but nothing rendered. How do I use `Html.EditorFor` when I dont have a model instance to pass to it?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're a bit confused about how to use `@Html.EditorFor()`. First,, your use of the lambda expression doesn't quite make sense, `model => new Person()`. If you want to create a new instance of a model then there's no need to use a lambda, just `new Person()` gives you that instance.

Second, you don't need an actual instance to pass into `@Html.EditorFor()`. The purpose of this method is to produce an html markup including an input field for a property or even multiple properties.

So let's say your `Person` model had an `Age` property, then you can create an edit field for that attribute by calling

`@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age)`

Now where does `model` come from? You have to define it in your view, so add this line to the top of your view file so that ASP.net knows which model to grab the `Age` attribute from,

`@model <namespace>.Models.Person`

The `namespace` is usually the name of your project, and if you don't put your models in the `Models` folder, then replace that with where ever your model is contained in.

Comment: Yep. Im definitely confused! So I should **not** be using `EditorFor` for the model itself and I only use it on rendering input fields for properties? If so, how should I be rendering the full form? Is it a best practice to put it in a partial and call with `@Html.Partial`?

Comment: You can use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m)` to generate all the form controls for your model, but usually you create an `EditorTempate` for your model to control the output

Comment: @StephenMuecke How would that work when there isn't an instance of the model to reference? As I am writing this all out, I'm thinking that maybe I need to redesign my application.

Comment: All you need is `@model Person` at the top of the view as Chris has noted. You do not need to pass a model to the view, but its best practice to do so in your controller, for example `return View(new Person());` if you just want to create a new `Person`

Comment: hey @Jeff I would suggest calling `@Html.EditorFor()` multiple times for the properties you want the user to give input for to generate the full form. And the model to be referenced will come from `@model <namespace>.Models.Person` in your view. If what I'm saying sounds greek to u and you don't mind some scaffolded/generated code, then try right clicking your action method in your controller class and select `Add View` and choose the `Create` template. If you have any more questions feel free to ask.